# Add library to Android Studio and import in class

Tags: class, android-studio, import

I would like to import the following library : https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOU
into my project so i can use the UByte/ULong... types as attributes the same way u can import and call a ByteBuffer for example. I followed this tutorial : [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio) but it didn't work and it kept telling me that it couldn't find the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

please Go to: File > New > Import Module .. select your downloaded Library

then Go to : File > Project structure > select App > dependencies tab > + Dependency Module Like in the this pic:

[image]

**Update**

ok, after taking a look at the library, just try to copy" jOOU/jOOU/src/main/java/org/joou/" folder inside one of your packages and it will work

Comment: Thx for the reply, but when I try to import the module, it tells me that I need to Specify the location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse project.

Comment: take a look at my updated answer, its working in my project

Comment: Found an alternative, instead of clicking module dependency, I clicked on Library dependency and searched for joou. I can import the project using import org.joou.UByte for example, the problem is that when I try to run the app, it shows me this error :

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.joou.UByte    
I checked and the library is in the "External Libraries" folder,